# Style with undefined instead of MuiHeader (@Material-ui v4)

Tags: material-ui

I have an SSR based @Material-ui v4.0.0 application.

I followed the docs to create the option of a transparent CardHeader.

```
import MuiCardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        '&$transparent': {
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
        },
    },
    transparent: {},
}));

const CardHeader = ({ transparent, ...rest }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return <MuiCardHeader classes={classes} transparent={transparent} {...rest} />;
};
```

The transparent header renders in a standard way and I see this as the generated `classes` object:

```
action:
"MuiCardHeader-action"
avatar:
"MuiCardHeader-avatar"
content:
"MuiCardHeader-content"
root:
"MuiCardHeader-root makeStyles-root-404"
subheader:
"MuiCardHeader-subheader"
title:
"MuiCardHeader-title"
transparent:
"undefined makeStyles-transparent-406"
```

The undefined obviously looks wrong. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the missing piece seems to be enabling the `className` through `clxs`. Poorly documented, I'm afraid.

```
const CardHeader = ({ transparent, ...rest }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MuiCardHeader
            classes={classes}
            className={clsx({
                [classes.transparent]: transparent
            })}
            {...rest}
        />
    );
};
```